# Android Project, Database(Server), Beginner

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to create an app where I can globally broadcast news to everyone who has installed my application. Let's take an example: Say there is a road under maintenance (between point A and point B). Now, I save this message onto the server, such that the message can be seen by all who have the app installed. How do I go about this? Can anyone tell me how to get started?

Comment: push notifications. GCM push notifications.

Comment: Thank you, i will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're essentially looking for are push notifications. GCM push notifications.

Here's the BroadcastReceiver just so I don't post a one-line answer:

```
 /**
 * This {@code WakefulBroadcastReceiver} takes care of creating and managing a
 * partial wake lock for your app. It passes off the work of processing the GCM
 * message to an {@code IntentService}, while ensuring that the device does not
 * go back to sleep in the transition. The {@code IntentService} calls
 * {@code GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent()} when it is ready to
 * release the wake lock.
 */

public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GCMIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

And here's the IntentService

```
/**
 * This {@code IntentService} does the actual handling of the GCM message.
 * {@code GcmBroadcastReceiver} (a {@code WakefulBroadcastReceiver}) holds a
 * partial wake lock for this service while the service does its work. When the
 * service is finished, it calls {@code completeWakefulIntent()} to release the
 * wake lock.
 */
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if(intent == null) {
        return;
    }
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (extras != null && !extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
         * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
         * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification(extras);
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification(extras);
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification(extras);
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "Received EXTRAS bundle: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
    private void sendNotification(Bundle msgBundle) {

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, splashIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.dpd_notification_icon).setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)).setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(current.msg)).setContentText(current.msg);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                mBuilder.setVibrate(pattern);

                Notification note = mBuilder.build();
                note.vibrate = pattern;

                if(note != lastNotification) {
                    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, note);
                    lastNotification = note;
                }

                Intent notificationMsg = new Intent(Constants.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
                notificationMsg.putExtra(Constants.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_TEXT, current.msg);
                notificationMsg.putExtra(Constants.PARCEL_UPDATE_SILENT, current.silent);
                notificationMsg.putExtra(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, NOTIFICATION_ID);
                        sendBroadcast(notificationMsg);

            }

            NOTIFICATION_ID++;
        }
```

You'll need the following permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

as well as

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".backend.push.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="my.package.name"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".backend.push.GCMIntentService"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommended:
Google Push do the work for you.

Not recommended:
Or you can develop your own service, checking if the server have some new message, but you need check on every X minutes or seconds (this causes a CPU, and RAM overload knowing that the Google Push is also doing it for other applications

Answer (score -1):

First of all , You need to know what is the 'HTTP'.It can connect your app and server.(You better learn something about TCP/IP.they are base of Http).

Then,maybe you can learn something about 'Thread' and 'Handle'.

Push the news into you server,and let your app to get them.

Comment: That solution requires you to poll the server constantly... -1